# MLE and Minimal Sufficiency of Parameters in a Piecewise Random Variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, sufficient-statistics

**Problem Setting:**
$X_i$ is i.i.d. from a piecewise distribution which is
$$
f_{\theta_1, \theta_2}(x) = \frac{1}{\theta_1+\theta_2}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta_1}}I_{[x>0]} + \frac{1}{\theta_1+\theta_2}e^{\frac{x}{\theta_2}}I_{[x \leq 0]}
$$
I want to figure out the minimal sufficient statistics for $\theta = [\theta_1,\theta_2]$ and find the maximum likelihood estimation for both of them.

**I try to use the factorization theorem, but I don't know how to deal with the indicator functions in the joint pdf $f_{\theta_1, \theta_2}(X)$, where $X = \{X_1, X_2,...,X_N\}$. Therefore, I am also wondering how can I take the derivative respect with $\theta$ but they have indicator functions in the joint pdf which seems the derivative cannot be applied due to discontinuity.**

Comment: Do not [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4063682/321264) please.

Comment: (a) The discontinuity is in $x$ not in $\theta$ (b) the indicator functions vanish from the likelihood by considering positive and negative observations separately.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-posted homework problem. It has been answered on math.SE.

Comment: If you can not answer the question, please don't speak out